# NodeJS Express and deflate/gzip compression

Tags: node.js, express, gzip, deflate

I've stucked with compression using from NodeJS Express v4.14. I have following code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var compression = require('compression');

function shouldCompress(req, res) {
  return true;
}

app.use(compression({ threshold: 0, filter: shouldCompress }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile('text.txt', { root: __dirname + '/dist' });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
});
```

I use NodeJS installed on Windows 7 64 bits. I run this example from Windows console such way:

```
SET DEBUG=compression
SET NODE_ENV=production
node index.js
```

But when I'm trying to run this code I do not see that my returned result is compressed. Here is a screenshot done from Firefox browser.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSNUs.jpg

So you can see that this text file is not compressed while sending.
Do you have any suggestions what is the cause of this ?

In Windows console I can see debug messages like this:

```
compression gzip compression +10ms
```

so it seems that compression code is running. Also I tried to clear browser 
cache but it did not help me.

Thanks in advance.
Regards
Stan

UPDATE:
I've tried to replace SendFile call by using a standard JADE-template that I filled with plain text. Here is a full example:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var compression = require('compression');

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

function shouldCompress(req, res) {
  return true;
}

app.use(compression({ threshold: 0, filter: shouldCompress }));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));

app.all("/*", function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port)
});
```

But it also has not led to success. You can see a screenshot from Firefox browser.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/46FLh.jpg

I also see compression debug output but compression does not work for some reason.

Comment: I suppose that the compression does not work for `sendFile`.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not help. See my post update above for details.

Comment: Perhaps there is a problem with browser setting. I create app and run on Win7 x32 and it works fine in FF http://sgeproject.narod.ru/node/compression.zip

Comment: It's interesting thing. I just right now tried to run both examples on my home PC that has Ubunty 16.04 installed. And both examples work properly with compression. So this is a problem with my Windows 7 environment. But what it is may be how do you think ? I did not changed manually any browser settings... It's a very strange situation for me.

Comment: I don't have idea because I cann't repeat this problem on my PC. Try `set DEBUG=express:router compression`.

Comment: drapal, i use compression on node but nothing is compressed. i follow your thread